# (simple) CSV download with special characters drives me nuts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, character-encoding, download

this one is driving me nuts.
And last week i thougt i cracked the nut, but unfortunately not....

so i want to create a CSV download for other users to open up in MS-Word (they want the CSV format)

so i end up with this code in a MVC2 controller:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PersonalMessages.csv");
Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
string s = new DownloadService().GetAddresses();
Response.Write(s);
Response.End();
return null;
```

the string 's' contains (among other info) these chars: é å æ É à

When i open it in notepad: OK

when i open it in Notepad++: Ok

when i open it up in Excel: Not ok, it shows this:   Ã© Ã¥ Ã¦ Ã‰ Ã

(when i open it up in Notepadd++, it says it is in UTF8 encoding without BOM, whatever i tried with UTF8 encodings with booleans in the constructor to get the BOM in, it didn;t work out)

So i asked a question last week, and the answer was to let the GetAddresses() function return a byte array.

So i did convert my text using this:

```
// C# to convert a string to a byte array.
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.UnicodeEncoding encoding = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

, and wrote the byte array in the response and all was fine! Notepad, notepad++ and Excel!
Great, live is good.

But then i found out they we're opening up the file in Word. Well, no problem i thought.

But then they aid: Word can not open the file (diretly), **it asks for the encoding first**, and that is a problem because they are using it in an automated process.

When they open the file in Notepad and save it as unicode, all goes well.

I've also tried this in the action method:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode ;
Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

but that didn't help out.

Does anybody has any clue?

Comment: the down side of a problem where you tried a lot is that it becomes such a large story to read for others, credit for you if you took the time to read it all and also read this comment....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    var data = encoding.GetBytes("éåæÉà;some other value");
    return File(data, "application/csv", "PersonalMessages.csv");
}
```

Also notice the slight simplification and the usage of `FileResult`.

Another possibility which is what I would recommend you is to explicitly append the preamble so that Excel can recognize the UTF-8 encoding:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("éåæÉà;some other value");
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(data).ToArray();
    return File(result, "application/csv;charset=utf-8", "PersonalMessages.csv");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work out. I've tried both solutions you said, evrn down to literally that code, so i deleted my code so that would not be in the way. Notepad, notepad++ and excel like the code, but when i save the file to disk and open it with Ms-Word (10), it (Word) asks what encoding the file is in....

Comment: @Michel, Word always does this when it encounters non ASCII characters. Try saving a CSV file in Excel which contains those special characters and then open it in Word. It will ask you about the encoding.

Comment: Wow. That sucks i think (there will probably be a good reason for it). I tried it with notepad too: create new file, paste this 'éåæÉà', close and save, open it up with Word, and indeed, Word asks about the encoding. The client say when they explicitly save it as unicode from notepad, Word does open it up without questions (they're using it as the source for mailmerge). when I save it as unicode from notepad and open it up in Word (not as mailmerge) it however DOES ask for the encoding.

Comment: I've been receiving the error "The non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used as a method". Someone knows why is it happening?

Comment: In my case, it was just a `’` apostrophe issue in Excel. The first solution worked fine for me! I also checked it opening the file in MS Word and also worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried many encodings, the one that worked is `Windows-1252` :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\"");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
Response.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myDataLines));
Response.End();
```

Comment: use Response.ContentEncoding = my-locale-encoding works for me

Answer (score 2):

Use ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

Its working fine.

i tried in XLSX document.